# Nested Form Implementation Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-forms, nested-form-for

I recently decided to test out [Nested Form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form). Everything from installing the gem up to modifying the respective models went nicely... and then my luck ran out when I tried the actual thing.

**Models**

Like all other friendship models, `User` is self-referencing as `:friend`.

```
class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
end
```

This is my Paperclip model:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :document

    FILE_FORMAT = ["Audio", "Document", "Image", "Video"]
end
```

This one is generated through Devise:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :login

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "120x120!" }

    has_many :uploads
    has_many :shares
    has_many :friends, :through => :shares
    has_many :inverse_shares, :class_name => "Share", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
    has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_shares, :source => :user

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads
end
```

**Forms**

This was my non-nested form, which worked correctly:

```
<%= simple_form_for(upload, defaults: { wrapper_html: { class: 'form-group' }, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } }, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :file_name, label: "File Name:", input_html: {size: 19} %>
    <br /><br />
    <%= f.input :file_type, as: :select, collection: Upload::FILE_FORMAT, label: "File Type:" %>
    <br /><br />
    <%= f.input :document, as: :file, label: "File Path:" %>
    <br /><br />
    <%= f.submit "Upload File" %>
<% end %>
```

This is the form I am trying to fix:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @user, url: uploads_path(@user), html: { method: :post } do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :uploads do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.input :file_name, label: "File Name:", input_html: {size: 19} %>
  <br /><br />
  <%= ff.input :file_type, as: :select, collection: Upload::FILE_FORMAT, label: "File Type:" %>
  <br />
  <%= ff.input :document, as: :file, label: "File Path:" %>
  <br /><br />
  <%= ff.submit "Upload File" %>
  <br /><br />
<%= ff.link_to_remove "Remove Document" %>
<% end %>
<%= f.link_to_add "Add Document", :uploads %>
<% end %>
```

**Errors Encountered**

A. Using `@upload` (which is `@upload = Upload.new` in the controller) gives an `ArgumentError in Uploads#new`.

`<%= simple_nested_form_for @upload, url: uploads_path(@upload), html: { method: :post } do |f| %>`

`Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :uploads association.`

B. The form I am trying to fix (see Forms section, `@user = current_user`) seems to present itself as an edit request. `/uploads/new` loads all the forms, with the corresponding values of all user `:uploads`, instead of allowing the forms to be filled up.

C. Submitting via the same form gives a `param not found: upload` error.

`ActionController::ParameterMissing in UploadsController#create`

**Question**

How should the nested form be rectified so as to allow it to function as a normal form should?

Thank you.

Comment: As the [documentation suggests](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), you should also add `attr_accessible :uploads_attributes` to `User` model.

Comment: Hello. Adding the said line, or any `attr_accessible` lines for that matter, prevents me from running `rails s` as it throws out a screenful of errors. If it is of any relation, I have these values permitted in a `configure_permitted_parameters` method in `application_controller.rb`.

Comment: @vee I added `gem 'protected_attributes'` in order to make `attr_accessible` work. Error C is still present.